# formControlName does not save all value from select

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

The formControlName set only the surname in my database. How can i save the forname & surname?

```
<mat-select formControlName="date_customer">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.forname && ' ' && customer.surname">{{ customer.forname }} {{ customer.surname }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: `[value]="customer.forname + ' ' + customer.surname">`

Comment: You are welcome! :)